# Eclipse/Android - Debug Configuration - Device?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have set up a "Debug Configuration" to debug my Android project. However to get it to debug on a device (HTC Desire) I have to set the Configuration's "Target" to "Manual", there seems to be no way to set in the Debug Configuration that it should go to a selected Device.

It does work, but each debug session I have to "Manually" choose the HTC device from the dialog.

Can I set it to always to go the Device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is not a way to do this.

Comment: damn it! I am so frustrated... I know it has worked for me as OP wanted to a while ago but now does no more :(